# Cin entry fails when previous calls do not

Tags: c++, cin

I have this section of code for generating an array of randomly generated and sorted ints, but the nosearch cin quits the program. Calling Cin.ignore() & cin.clear() before and/or after this line does not correct this, no error message is shown, the program just quits as soon as I hit enter on that section. This is the only statement to do this.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctime>
#include "search.hpp" //a function called sarch is here, program quits before sarch is called. 

using namespace std;

int main () {
    srand(time(0));
    int tenn;
    int minrange;
    int maxrange;
    cout << "Enter the number of integers: ";
    cin >> tenn;
    cout << endl << "Enter the lower limit: ";
    cin >> minrange;
    cout << endl << "Enter the upper limit: ";
    cin >> maxrange;

    int *arr = new int(tenn*10);

    for (int i = 0; i < tenn*10; i++){
        *(arr+i) = (rand() % maxrange) + minrange;
    }
    cout << "list, unsorted: " << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < tenn*10; i++){
        cout << *(arr+i) << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < tenn*10; i++){
       
        int low = i;
        for (int j = i; j < tenn*10; j++){
            if (*(arr+j) < *(arr+low)){
                low = j;
            }
        }
        int temp = *(arr+i);
        *(arr+i) = *(arr+low);
        *(arr+low) = temp;
    }

    cout << "sorted list: " << endl;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < tenn*10; i++){
        cout << *(arr+i) << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;

    int nosearch;
    cout << "Enter the number of values you wish to search for: " << endl;
    //The next cin will fail
    cin >> nosearch;
    
    cout << "v";
//more code here...
```

I use a makefile to compile the code, and when I run it in terminal, this is what happens:

```
>./Needle.exe
Enter the number of integers: 2

Enter the lower limit: 0

Enter the upper limit: 10
list, unsorted:
9 4 6 2 4 5 2 9 1 4 7 8 3 4 9 4 6 7 9 9
sorted list:
1 2 2 3 4 4 4 4 4 5 6 6 7 7 8 9 9 9 9 9
Enter the number of values you wish to search for:
3

>
```

I can only assume something I did above triggered this error, which is why I included so much of the code.

Comment: `int *arr = new int(tenn*10);` does not create an array, it is `int *arr = new int; *arr = tenn*10;`

Comment: Corrected and Error no longer occurs. Unsure why the syntax still behaves like an array or why it was causing the cin error.

Comment: *why the syntax still behaves like an array* Where have you seen ( ) in C++ arrays?

Comment: there probably isn't any problem with `cin`, note that `cout << "v";` won't print "v" immediately (it will only buffer it), so the error would've occurred anywhere before its flush